# Client secret not found in docker

Tags: django, docker, google-calendar-api

I am using the google calendar API in my django project. I have two calendars connected which was working fine until i tried to run my project in a docker container.

Now the client_secret.json files are not found anymore even though they are still in the same folder and practically nothing has changed.

The error is this:

> Exception Value: ('Error opening file', 'client_secret.json', 'No such
>   file or directory', 2)

So my question is: what am i missing?

Here is a link to a google drive folder containing both settings.py and the docker file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mzek7-S8QNIrEt_sI6jklMNlLkHXURkw

Comment: can you paste your docker and settings file ??

Comment: added a link in the description =)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the google API changed a bit (you need a credentials.json which generates a token.json) - for some reason it still worked in my django project but not in the docker container.

Updating the code did the trick.

Cheers!